# Pandas: Change cell value based on other column and the value itself

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas df:

```
category1   category2
A           B
A           C
B           NaN
A           NaN
```

And I want to change values in `category2` to `D` if the following conditions are met:

- `category1 == A`
- `category2 == NaN`

Therefore my expected output would be:

```
category1   category2
A           B
A           C
B           NaN
A           D
```

I tried two ways:

```
df.loc[((df.category1 == "A") & (df.category2 == 'nan')), "category2"] = "D" # doesn't change anything
```

and

```
import numpy as np
df['category2'] = np.where(((df['category1'] == 'A') & (df['category2'] == "")), "D")
# ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

Why doesn't neither of the lines work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below:

```
df.loc[df.category2.isna()&df.category1.eq('A'),'category2']='D'
print(df)
```

---

```
  category1 category2
0         A         B
1         A         C
2         B       NaN
3         A         D
```

Comment: Just to clear, the main reason why this works is because of the `.isna()` (could also use `.isnull()`, it's not the use of `.eq()` (you could still use `=='A'` instead of `.eq('A')` for the same result). 
Your original code didn't work bc `'nan'` nor `""` are equal to `NaN`. The safest way to test if a value is null in pandas is `.isnull()`

Answer (score 2):

The error:

> ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given

Is telling you that `np.where` needs a value from which to choose for both when the condition is `True`, and *also* `False`. In your case it only knows that when it is `True` you want a `D`. Instead do:

```
df['category2'] = np.where(((df['category1'] == 'A') & (df['category2'].isna())),
                             "D", df['category2'])
```

Comment: `np.where` solution is a bit faster when writing a single column comparing to loc[] I guess.